# Date/Time formatting Scala

Tags: scala, java-time

I'm trying to assert date and time displayed on the page

Problem is it's returning value of "2017-03-11T09:00" instead of "2017-03-11 09:00:00" and I'm confused why as the pattern = yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Any ideas?

```
def getDate :String = {
val timeStamp = find(xpath("//*[@id=\"content\"]/article/div/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/div/p[4]")).get.underlying.getText
val stripDate: Array[String] = timeStamp.split("Timestamp:\n")
stripDate(1)
}


def datePattern(date: String): LocalDateTime = {
val pattern: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
val result = LocalDateTime.parse(date, pattern)
result
}

def checkDatePattern() = datePattern(getDate).toString shouldBe getDate
```

Comment: How does your date string look like?

Comment: why don't you use SimpleDateFormat ?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan, `SimpleDateFormat` is long outdated, and judging from the number of questions on Stack Overflow it is causing a lot of trouble for very many. `DateTimeFormatter` (used in the question) is the modern replacement, it is much nicer to work with and tends to give fewer unpleasant surprises.

Answer (score 3):

The `DateTimeFormatter` only gets used for the parse operation. It doesn't influence the result of `toString`. If you want to convert your `LocalDateTime` to a `String` in a certain format you have to call

```
date.format(pattern)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get the result I wanted by just deleting some parts of the code. As long as the date is in displayed in the correct format, the test passes if it's displayed in an incorrect format it fails, which is good enough for me. Thanks for your input. CASE CLOSED

```
 def getDate :String = {
val timeStamp = find(xpath("//*[@id=\"content\"]/article/div/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/div/p[4]")).get.underlying.getText
val stripDate: Array[String] = timeStamp.split("Timestamp:\n")
stripDate(1)
 }


def datePattern(date: String): LocalDateTime = {
val pattern: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
LocalDateTime.parse(date, pattern)
}

def checkDatePattern() = datePattern(getDate)
```